# flyway.conf file ignore location property

Tags: java, spring-boot, migration, flyway

I have Spring Boot project with flyway.conf file inside. My project structure looks like:

```
springBootMainFolder/flyway.conf
springBootMainFolder/src/main/java/com/example/db/migration/V1__Some_migration.java
springBootMainFolder/src/main/resources/db/migration/V2_Another_migration.sql
```

As I understand, by default, flyway points location to `db/migration` (which is my third folder with files from list), and if I want to change it, I can just tell it to flyway inside `flyway.conf` file. Which is looks like:

```
flyway.locations=db.migration,classpath:db.migration
flyway.user=test
flyway.password=test
flyway.schemas=test
flyway.url=postgresql://test:5442/test
```

And when I run migrations, only migrations from third folder (`springBootMainFolder/src/main/resources/db/migration`) are visible, and even if I'm trying to set another dumb location in `flyway.locations` property it is got ignored and it starts to find under `db.migration` folder. Why it can be ignored and how I can set it?

Comment: Also one mention, that I'm using mavens `flyway-maven-plugin` with version `8.5.13`. And all other properties like `flyway.user` or `flyway.url` got read properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't understood why location property was ignored from `flyway.conf` file, but if I place this property under `configuration` tag of `flyway-maven-plugin` plugin, it works.